# Vimeo api to wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, rest

I have listed the vimeo videos from a channel using vimeo api using php
Now i want to upload all the videos as a post to wordpress custom postype how to do that?
each time a new video i published it should add the videos as a post to custom postype

Answer (score 0):

To create a post in WordPress, you can use the below code.

***Step1:***

Look for the Vimeo webhooks option, which will let you know when a new Vimeo video is published. By doing so, you can get the details of the video and then use that information to create a post in WordPress.

***Vimeo API link:*** https://developer.vimeo.com/help

***Zapier Vimeo Integration Link:*** https://zapier.com/apps/vimeo/integrations/webhook

***Step2:***

```
/**
 * A function used to programmatically create a post in WordPress. The slug, author ID, and title
 * are defined within the context of the function.
 *
 * @returns -1 if the post was never created, -2 if a post with the same title exists, or the ID
 *          of the post if successful.
 */
function programmatically_create_post() {

    // Initialize the page ID to -1. This indicates no action has been taken.
    $post_id = -1;

    // Setup the author, slug, and title for the post
    $author_id = 1;
    $slug = 'example-post';
    $title = 'My Example Post';

    // If the page doesn't already exist, then create it
    if( null == get_page_by_title( $title ) ) {

        // Set the post ID so that we know the post was created successfully
        $post_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
                'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
                'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
                'post_name'     =>  $slug,
                'post_title'        =>  $title,
                'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                'post_type'     =>  'post'
            )
        );

    // Otherwise, we'll stop
    } else {

            // Arbitrarily use -2 to indicate that the page with the title already exists
            $post_id = -2;

    } // end if

} // end programmatically_create_post
add_filter( 'after_setup_theme', 'programmatically_create_post' );
```